# Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Lesson[]>'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am using a Angular 8 application. And I am using the Observable pattern form rxjs. But I still get an error on the Observable line.

Googled on the error of course. But didn find the correct answare.

So I Importated this:

```
import { Subject, Observer, Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

And I have this line:

```
    public lessonList$: Observable<Lesson[]> = this.lessonListSubject.asObservable();
```

But I still get this error:

```
Type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Lesson[]>'.
  Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Lesson[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)
```

That the error will dissapear.

Thank you

oke, this is the interface Lesson:

```
export interface Lesson {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    duration?: string;
    completed?: boolean;

}
```

This is the whole file:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Lesson } from '../shared/model/lesson';
import { Subject, Observer, Observable } from 'rxjs';


class DataStore {

    private lessons: Lesson[] = [];

    private lessonListSubject = new Subject();

    public lessonList$: Observable<Lesson[]> = this.lessonListSubject.asObservable();



    initaliseLessonList(newList: Lesson[]) {
        this.lessons = _.clone(newList);
        this.broadCast();


    }
    addLesson(newLesson: Lesson) {

        this.lessons.push(newLesson);
        this.broadCast();
    }

    deleteLesson(deleted: Lesson) {
        _.remove(this.lessons, lesson => lesson.id === deleted.id);
        this.broadCast();


    }

    toggleView(toggled: Lesson) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: no-shadowed-variable
        const lesson = _.find(this.lessons, lesson => lesson.id === toggled.id);

        lesson.completed = !lesson.completed;
        this.broadCast();


    }

    broadCast() {
        this.lessonListSubject.next(_.cloneDeep(this.lessons));

    }
}

export const store = new DataStore();
```

Comment: Given the code you posted, all we can say is: read the error message: it tells you wnat is wrong in the code you didn't post.

Comment: yes, oke, I edit the post

Comment: And we still don't know anything about `this.lessonListSubject`. The error message tells you that this is where the problem is: you can't assign the value `this.lessonListSubject.asObservable()` to lessonList$ because it doesn't have the right type.

Comment: I posted the entire file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
private lessonListSubject = new Subject();
```

by

```
private lessonListSubject = new Subject<Lesson[]>();
```

That way, you have a `Subject<Lesson[]>` and not a `Subject<unknown>`.